# Why do I get an "ambiguous column name: account.accrued"?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to execute an [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) query to update a column in my accounts table:

```
UPDATE account SET accrued = (account.accrued + ((product.intrate/365)*balance))
FROM account
JOIN customer ON customer.custid = account.custid
JOIN product ON product.prodid = account.prodid
WHERE active = 1
```

I have tried this, but it comes up with the result

> ambiguous column name: account.accrued

```
UPDATE a SET accrued = (a.accrued + ((p.intrate/365)*balance))
FROM account a
JOIN customer c ON c.custid = a.custid
JOIN product p ON p.prodid = a.prodid
WHERE active = 1
```

I have also tried that query, but the result comes up with no such table a. If I take out the column accrued from the calculation I then get the same error for the balance column.

The column accrued is only in the one table, *account*.

Comment: What is your version of SQLite?

Comment: DB Browser for SQLite Version 3.12.1, that is what im using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax for SQLite:

```
UPDATE account AS a 
SET accrued = (a.accrued + ((p.intrate/365)*balance))
FROM customer c JOIN product p 
ON p.prodid = a.prodid
WHERE c.custid = a.custid AND active = 1
```

Note that you should qualify all the column names (except the column that is updated after `SET`) with the table name/alias to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: That seems to have worked nicely,  thank you

Comment: hi i wonder if you could help with adding it to my windows forms application? ive updated the question to include it  thanks

Comment: @adrian38 I can't help you with windows forms. But from the syntax error I believe that your app uses an older version of SQLite that does not support the FROM clause in an UPDATE statement. The query may work in DB Browser for SQLite because it uses SQLite 3.33.0 Also, don't add new requirements in an existing question. By doing so you invalidate the answer that you accepted.